# Как изменить список объявленный в классе с помощью метода этого же класса

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Изучая ООП, выполнял задание по создание класса, который должен содержать в себе значения координат в списке и написать классе метод, с помощью которого можно менять значение координат.

При выполнении функции `changeCoords` питон выдает ошибку - 
**`ubresolved reference`**.

```
class Point:
    coords = [1, 2, 3]

    def __init__(self, x = coords[0], y  = coords[1], z = coords[2]):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y 
        self.z = z

    def changeCoords(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
        coords[0] = x
        coords[1] = y
        coords[2] = z

pt = Point()
print(pt.changeCoords(4, 5, 6))
```

Ввопрос - почему нельзя в методе сослаться на список, объявленный в этом же классе и как все таки с помощью метода класса поменять список `coords`?

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы сделали `coords` объектом класса:

```
coords = [1, 2, 3]
```

Но чтобы обращаться к объекту `coords` в других методах этого класса
надо добавить **`self`**:

```
    self.coords[0] = x
    self.coords[1] = y
    self.coords[2] = z
```

---

```
class Point(object):
    coords = [1, 2, 3]

    def __init__(self, x=coords[0], y=coords[1], z=coords[2]):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y 
        self.z = z
        print(f'\nx={x}, y={y}, z={z}\n')

    def changeCoords(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
        self.coords[0] = x
        self.coords[1] = y
        self.coords[2] = z
        return self.coords


pt = Point()

print(f'111 pt.coords --> {pt.coords}\n')

print(pt.changeCoords(4, 5, 6))
print(f'222 pt.coords --> {pt.coords}\n')

print(pt.changeCoords())
print(f'333 pt.coords --> {pt.coords}\n')

print(pt.changeCoords(777))
print(f'444 pt.coords --> {pt.coords}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень важно при изучении `ООП` ли, `функционального программирования` ли, или любой другой `парадигмы программирования` уметь читать ошибки.

1. `NameError: name 'coords' is not defined` - ошибка появилась в следствии пропущенного `self`.
2. это не столько ошибка сколько видимо недопонимание,
   `self.x` это совсем не то что `self.coords[0]` поэтому присваивания в конструкторе класса несколько избыточны, там можно использовать `changeCoords`
3. Совсем не обязательно знать особенности языка сразу, но все же иногда полезно, например тело метода
   `changeCoords` можно записать короче (не обязательно).
4. Раз уж мы говорим про `ООП` то для получения значений нужно использовать соответсвующий метод, `changeCoords` обычно подобные методы не возвращают ничего.

таким образом у нас получается:

```
class Point:
    coords = [1, 2, 3]

    def __init__(self, x = coords[0], y  = coords[1], z = coords[2]):
        self.changeCoords(x, y, z)

    def changeCoords(self, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0):
        self.coords = [x, y, z]

    def getCoords(self):
        return self.coords 

pt = Point()
pt.changeCoords(4, 5, 6)
print(pt.getCoords())
```